# decimal point in product quantity using magento

Tags: php, magento

I want to set & show 3 digit precisions in product quantity using magento.
E.g. 0.100,0.250 etc.

Please suggest how can I set it?

Note: My Magento version is 1.9.0.1

Comment: @Hannes, thanks for reply. If any customer want to buy a product like almonds in grams(e.g.100 grams) then that customer can have possible to purchase almonds in grams by putting it's quantity as 0.100 in quantity textbox. And I want to show that product quantity, currently it shows 0.1 in cart, and I want to show that quantity everywhere, is there any solution for it ?

Comment: Please add your comment to your question. It would be great if you can add what you have tried/researched so far and what difficulties you encountered.

Answer (score 2):

This is possible using native Magento functionality.

Simply navigate to the product you wish to use this inventory logic and go to the inventory tab. Once it is set to managed stock, you can choose Yes for `Qty Uses Decimals` and then check `Enable Qty Increments` and set the `Qty Increments` value to 0.100.

Comment: thanks for reply. I made these changes but no luck. Please see what problem I faced & what I need ?
Problem: When I put product quantity like 0.100 then will show 0.1 on product page(product quantity textbox), cart page (product quantity textbox), in my cart 0.1 items (in top).
Expected: Need to show like 0.100 wherever the product quantity shows. (In short want to show 3 digit precisions).
Note: my magento version is 1.9.0.1,
Thanks